# How to correctly set curly braces to variable in csh

Tags: csh, curly-braces

When trying to set a string to a variable in csh i'm getting "Missing }." as shown by the example below.

```
set testout='{"error":"", "data":""}'
echo $testout
Missing }.
```

I can't modify the string as the actual command I wish to run looks like the below, and this is just the string that is returned:

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: Basic 1234" -XPOST -F host1=$USER@$HOST $URL
{"error":"", "data":""}

set curltest="`curl -s -H 'Authorization: Basic 1234' -XPOST -F host1=$USER@$HOST $URL`"
Missing }.
```

How do you set a variable like this in csh?

Comment: Do you need to escape anything, such as the colons?

Comment: Try this:
"echo $testout:q"

Comment: @Šerg that works. I'm guessing the echo is confused as to the format.